# Why my custom view android takes all the space of my screen?

Tags: android, resize, android-wrap-content

Let's take simple `CustomView` as an example

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        super.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(20,20,220,220,new Paint());
    }

}
```

In my `MainActivity` I add my `View` in a `LinearLayout`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
linearLayout.addView(new MyView(this));
linearLayout.addView(new MyView(this));
```

As u can see change to the background color, the first `view` MyView take up all the space

[image]

I want my two `views` to only occupy the black space. `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
MyView mView = new MyView(this);
mView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
linearLayout.addView(mView);